# How to set phantomjs default font?

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, phantomjs

I use a Font on pages with Chinese characters on it. And when `Phantomjs` encounters Chinese characters that are not included in the font, it just uses the default font for that specific characters.

So how shall I set the default font for phantomjs to the one I choose, so that the characters missing displayed in the default font would have a similar appearence as the others displayed in that Font.

Answer (score 0):

For better portability, I usually set fonts in CSS. This only works locally of course because of the size of Chinese font files. Here is an example for Russian:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sanslight';
    src: url('cyrillic/opensans-light.svg#open_sanslight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can move the font you want to use into the font directory, for example, on Ubuntu,

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype
```